# How to query for an element inside a dom-repeat

Tags: binding, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have been scouring the web for a clear answer on how to query for an element generated by a dom-repeat element from Dart code.

sample.html

```
<dom-module id="so-sample>
  <style>...</style>
<template>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[cars]] as="car>
    ...
    <paper-button on-click="buttonClicked">Button</paper-button>

    <paper-dialog id="dialog">
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>
</template>
```

sample.dart

I'll omit the boilerplate code here, such as imports or the query to my database to fill the **cars** property ; everything works fine.

```dart
...
@reflectable
void buttonClicked(e, [_])
{
  PaperDialog infos = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#dialog");

  infos.open();
}
```

This generates the following error :
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined`

I have tried several 'solutions', which are not, since nothing works.
The only thing I saw on quite a lot of threads is to use `Timer.run()` and write my code in the callback, but that seems like a hack. Why would I need a timer ?

I understand my problem may be that the content of the dom-repeat is generated lazily, and I query the items 'before' they are added to the local DOM.

Another advice I didn't follow is to use Mutation Observers. I read in the polymer API documentation that the observeNodes method should be used instead, as it internally uses MO to handle indexing the elements, but it again seems a bit complicated just to open a dialog.

My final objective is to bind the button of each generated model to a dedicated paper-dialog to display additional information on the item.
Has anyone ever done that ? (I should hope so :p)

Thanks for your time !

**Update 1:**

After reading Gunter's advices, although none of them actually worked by themselves, the fact that the IDs aren't mangled inside a dom-repeat made me think and query **paper-dialog** instead of the id itself, and now my dialog pops up !

sample.dart:

```dart
PaperDialog infos = Polymer.dom(root).querySelector("paper-dialog");

infos.open();
```

I now hope that each button will call the associated dialog, since I'll bind data inside the dialog relative to the item I clicked ~

**Update 2:**

So, nope, the data binding didn't work as expected: All buttons were bound to the item at index 0, just as I feared. I tried several ways to query the correct **paper-dialog** but nothing worked. The only 'workaround' I found is to query all the paper-dialog into a list and then get the **'index-th'** element from that list.

```
@reflectable
void buttonClicked(e, [_])
{
  var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(e);
  List<PaperDialog> dialogs = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll("paper-dialog");
  dialogs[model.index].open();
}
```

This code definitely works, but it feels kind of a waste of resources to get **all the elements** when you really only need one and you already know which one.

So yeah, my initial problem is solved, but I still wonder why I couldn't query the dialogs from their id:

```
...
<paper-dialog id="dialog-[[index]]">
...
</paper-dialog>
```

```
@reflectable
void buttonClicked(e, [_])
{
  var model = new DomRepeatModel.fromEvent(e);
  PaperDialog dialog = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("dialog-${model.index}");
  dialog.open();
}
```

With this code, **dialog** is always null, although I can find those dialogs, correctly id-ied, in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Polymers DOM API with shady DOM (default). If you enable shadow DOM your code would probably work as well.

```
PaperDialog infos = new Polymer.dom(this).querySelector("#dialog")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work either.

With the new keyword, my IDE complains about Polymer not having a dom constructor, builds correctly anyway, and when I click the button, i get and Uncaught error in the is_helper file (which is not mine).
Without the new keyword, my IDE is happy, bu I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hJ' of null`

Not that different than before

Comment: Another problem is, that you have multiple elements with the same id. You can also try `new Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector()` or just `root.querySelector()`

Comment: Yeah I was wondering how things would work with mutiple elements with the same id. I considered polymer would 'mangle' it~

Comment: As far as I know - no. With full shadow DOM the shadow DOM is it's own document so they don't collide with ids outside the element, but ids within one shadow DOM still need to be unique.

Comment: As mentioned in my update to my question, thanks for your help :) Your combined ideas appear to work correctly !

Comment: Yes, as I expected, all dialogs are bound to the same item :/ Not sure if I should open a new thread or not ?

Comment: You need to generate unique ids. You can use `index`. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates but don't use number-only ids, that doesn't work well AFAIK. The need to start with an non-number character.

Comment: I read both versions of this page -- the one on the Dart.Polymer github and the one you linked -- but didn't actually find anything usefull. I just thought of appending the index to my ids. Would that work ?

Comment: You can use the `index` variable to calculate unique ids. `id="{{calcId(index)}}"` ... `@reflectable calcId (id) => return 'd$id';`

Comment: Yeah I was just testing something like this, thanks ;)